# Find Cauchy principal values of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x^2+4)(x^2-2x+5)}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

I have been asked to find the Cauchy principal vlaues of the following problem using residues:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x^2+4)(x^2-2x+5)}\,dx$

So far I have taken $\oint_C\frac{z}{(z^2+4)(z^2-2z+5)}\,dz$

which gives me:

$2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}\biggl[\frac{z}{(z^2+4)(z^2-2z+5)}\biggl]$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: What are the residues on the real line?  (If there are none, why not compute the actual integral, instead of the P.V.?)  What are the residues off the real line?  What contour $C$ will you use, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

factor the denominator.

$\frac {z}{(z+2i)(z-2i)(z-1+2i)(z-1-2i)}$

We only care about the poles in the upper half-plane.

You have poles at $z = 2i, z = 1+2i$

at $z=2i$

$Res f(z) = \lim_\limits{z\to 2i} (z-2i)f(z) =  \frac {2i}{(4i)(-1+4i)(-1)} = \frac {1+4i}{2(17)} = \frac {1}{34} + \frac {2i}{17} $

and at  $z = 1+2i$

$Res f(z) = \frac {1+2i}{(1+4i)(1)(4i)} = \frac {(1+2i)(1-4i)}{(17)(4i)} = \frac {9 - 2i}{(17)(4i)} = -\frac{9i}{68} - \frac {1}{34}$

add them together

$2\pi i \left(\frac {-i}{68}\right) = \frac {\pi}{34}$

Comment: That's where I was loosing myself! I didn't realise I only used the upper half of the plane, thank you!

Comment: The contour is the interval on the real line $[-R, R]$, together with the semi-cricle of radius $R$  (and then we take the limit a $R$ goes to infinity.  This contour encloses the upper half-plane.  It remains to be shown that along the path of the semi-circle the path integral is 0, which is a necessary but in this case, easy step.

Comment: An interesting observation: Isn't it so nice that the $1/34$ terms nicely cancel?

Comment: @imranfat It would be more curious if they didn't! (and they didn't for me the first time through, a nice way to check my work.)